# adding a space to every space in a string, then cycling back around until length is met

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following while loop as part of my text justify function.  The idea is that I have text strings (`str`) that need to be justified (spaces added to existing spaces in between words) to equal to a given length (`len`)

The catch is  I can only add one space to an existing space at a time before I iterate over to the next space in the string and add another space there. If that's it for all spaces in the string and it's still not at the required length, I cycle back over to the original space (now two spaces) and add another.  Then it goes to the next space between words and so on and so on.  The idea is that any spaces between words in the string should not have a differential of more than one space (i.e. `Lorem---ipsum--dolor--sit`, not `Lorem----ipsum--dolor-sit`)

From my research, I decided that using a `substring` method off the original string to add that first extra space, then I will increment the index and move to the next space in the string and repeat the add.  Here's my code:

```
var indexOf = str.indexOf(" ", 0);

if ( indexOf > -1 ) {
    while ( indexOf > -1 && str.length < len ) {
        //using a regexp to find a space before a character
        var space  = /\s(?=\b)/.exec(str);
        str = str.substring(0, indexOf + 1) + " " + str.substring(indexOf + 1);
        //go to next space in string
        indexOf = str.indexOf(space, indexOf + 2);

        if ( indexOf === -1 ) {
            //loops back to beginning of string
            indexOf = str.indexOf(space, 0);
        }

    }
}
finalResults.push(str);
```

This code works most of the time, but I noticed that there are instances where the cycle of spacing is not correct.  For example, it generates the following string:
`sit----amet,--blandit`
when the correct iteration would be
`sit---amet,---blandit`

Any assistance in making this code properly iterate over every space (to add one space) in the string once, then cycling back around to the beginning of the string to start over until the desired length is achieved would be most appreciated.

Comment: What is the desired length of spaces? 3 between every word?

Comment: The desired length of spaces may vary.  All that matters is that there's no more than 1-space differential between the nearest spaces.  
For example, if the string only has one space (two words in the string), the function can pad the strings until the string length hits the len variable.

Comment: If your string only has one space between words to start off with, why not use `replace`  evaluate the entire string instead of using a loop? https://jsfiddle.net/thbvbL4o/

Comment: No, that's just an example.  A string may have any number of words.

Comment: Does not matter if there is a million words or just two, if there is one space between the words they all will get replaced by whatever number of spaces you want with my example above.

Comment: I figured out a solution in the meantime.  I merely replace the `+ " " +` in the substring combination line with a `+ "-" +` (replaced the space concatenator between the substrings with a dash character).

Then, I replaced the `space` variable with `" "` in the `indexOf` expressions.

Finally, I used the replace method on `str2` to globally get rid of the dashes and to replace with spaces.

`str2 = str2.replace(/-/g, " ");`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more efficient to compute the number spaces required in the beginning.

```js
var s = "today is a friday";
var totalLength = 40;
var tokens = s.split(/\s+/);
var noSpaceLength = s.replace(/\s+/g,'').length;
var minSpace = Math.floor((totalLength - noSpaceLength)/(tokens.length-1));
var remainder = (totalLength - noSpaceLength) % (tokens.length-1);

var out = tokens[0];
for (var i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  var spaces = (i <= remainder ? minSpace+1 : minSpace);
  out += "-".repeat(spaces) + tokens[i];
}

$('#out').text(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Is there some reason you needed to include jQuery? I don't see where you're using it.

Comment: Not needed. Just there for the last statement.

Answer (score 1):

This solution

- splits the string (`s`) into words in an array (`a`)
- finds the number of spaces to be added between all words (`add`)
- finds the remainder of spaces to be added between first words (`rem`)
- then sticks the words with `add` spaces + one if `rem` is not exhausted

Code

```
var  s = "Caballo sin Nombre"; // assume one space between words
var len = 21; // desired length

var need = len - s.length;
var a = s.split(/ /); // split s

// need>0 and at least two words
if (need > 0 && a.length>1) {
     var add = Math.floor(need / (a.length-1)) + 1; // all spaces need that (+existing)
     var rem = need % (a.length-1); // remainder

     var sp = '';
     while (add-- > 0) sp += ' ';
     // replace
     var i,res = ''; // result
     for (i=0 ; i<a.length-1 ; i++) {
          res += a[i] + sp;
          if (rem-- > 0) res += ' '; // remainder
     }
     res += a[i];

     s = res;
}
console.log("'" + s + "' is " + s.length + " chars long.");
```

Answer (score 1):

This function adds the spaces using a global replace, carefully limiting the text size.

```
 function expand (txt, colwidth) {
   txt = txt.replace (/\s\s+/, ' ');        // Ensure no multiple spaces in txt

   for (var spaces = ' ',                   // Spaces to check for
            limit = colwidth - txt.length;  // number of additional spaces required
        limit > 0;                          // do while limit is positive
        spaces += ' ')                      // add 1 to spaces to search for
    txt = txt.replace (RegExp (spaces, 'g'), 
              function (r) { 
                // If limit > 0  then add a space else do not.
                return limit > 0 && --limit ? r + ' ' : r 
              });
    return txt;
 }

 for (var w = 21; w--;) console.log (expand ('this is a test.', w));
```

Shows this on console:

```
    this   is  a  test.
    this  is  a  test.
    this  is  a test.
    this  is a test.
 14 this is a test.
```